# How to install npm and other packages in ubuntu without internet

Tags: ubuntu, dockerfile, debian, ubuntu-18.04

we are using Ubuntu base image in our docker file and want to install node 16.x along with npm and then npm install -g @stoplight/spectral-cli in offline.

I am able to install node , but it seems in ubuntu npm is not bundled as part of the node installation and we have to sperately.

But I couldnt find anyway to install npm and spectral-cli without internet

Answer (score -1):

You can install like so:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#sudo su
USER root

#update and clean packages
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt install -y curl\
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - \
    &&  apt install -y nodejs

RUN npm install -g @stoplight/spectral-cli

ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "99999"]
```

inside the container

```
root@148132919d27:/# npm list -g
/usr/lib
+-- @stoplight/spectral-cli@6.6.0
+-- corepack@0.15.1
`-- npm@8.19.3
```

Dont let it with root access!

Comment: my environment is not having internet tp perform the apt-get installation as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean without internet. Where does your ubuntu base image comes from?

Comment: i am trying the image build where the apt-get commands wont work. because no internet connection to the ubunu and debian repo. So need to do offline installation

Comment: Can you build it somewhere else, push it to a docker registry and use it from there?

Comment: Our security policies are restricted for the same. Thats why trying for offline build

Comment: did you try to install it where you have the rights, then copy the files in side the docker image? I think to achieve that all correctly you need your own private npm and docker registry